# How to fill missing values in a subset of columns by matching values in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have a dataframe `df1 = DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','a','c'], 'col2':[1,2,1,1],'col3':['e1','e2',np.nan,'e5'],'col4':[4,5,6,6]})`.
I would like to fill in missing values in `col3` by looking up values/matching values in `col1` and `col2` to get the following output:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
a     1    e1   4 
b     2    e2   5 
a     1    e1   6 
c     1    e5   6
```

where values a and 1 in columns `col1` and `col2` return e1 for `col3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we can do is try use `groupby` with `ffill`

```
df1.fillna(df1.groupby(['col1','col2']).ffill(), inplace=True)
  col1  col2 col3  col4
0    a     1   e1     4
1    b     2   e2     5
2    a     1   e1     6
3    c     1   e5     6
```

Answer (score 2):

A very similar approach to YOBEN_S' answer (which I prefer), but using `fillna`:

```
df.col3 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).fillna(method='ffill').col3
```